# MPMoviePlayerController: Adding Subviews behind the control elements

Tags: ios, xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller, subviews, video-player

I add subviews to my MPMoviePlayerController depending on the current playback time to realize an interactive video.
At this point everything is working fine, except one thing:

The control elements of the `MPMoviePlayerController` appear under my subviews when the user touches inside the video.

E.g. One subview appears between 0:10 and 0:20 at the point (10/10). If the user wants to seek backward or forward the subview appears in front of the control elements of the player and blocks them.

I add the subviews like this:

```
overlay.hidden = FALSE;
[self.player.view addSubview:overlay];
```

Where `overlay` is a subclass of UIView.

Is there a way to control how the control elements appear or to add the subviews between the movie and the control elements?

I tried:

`[self.player.backgroundView addSubview:overlay];`
But here is the subview behind the movie.

The control elements aren't subviews of the `MPMoviePlayerController`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When debugging you should do a recursive print of your MPMoviePlayerController's view, that'll show you the entire subview hierarchy of that view. Like so:

po [[[self player] view] recursiveDescription]

Look for the MPVideoContainerView which has 4 subviews. The should insert your subview between 2 and 3, the MPVideoView which draws the video and the MPInlineVideoOverlay which holds all controls.

Comment: thanks. i tried. my answer is [[[self player] view] insertSubview: view atIndex: 2];